# JPA Criteria api join through embedded ID

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, criteria-api

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "place_revision")
public class PoiRevision {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pk.revision", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private Collection<PoiRevisionCategory> categoryMapping;
    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "place_revision__category")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.revision",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "place_revision_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.category",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
})
public class PoiRevisionCategory {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PoiRevisionCategoryId pk = new PoiRevisionCategoryId();
    // ...
}

@Embeddable
public class PoiRevisionCategoryId implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    private PoiRevision revision;
    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;
    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Section.class, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "category__section",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "section_id")
    )
    private Collection<Section> sections;
    // ...
}
```

And want to select `PoiRevisions` that have `Categories` that have some `Sections`.
I'm using Spring-data `Specification` to query the database for these entities.

My intent is to write something like:

```
Specification<PoiRevision> spec = new Specification<PoiRevision>() {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<PoiRevision> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        List<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList<>(CONDITION_COUNT);

        CollectionJoin<PoiRevision, PoiRevisionCategory> mapping = root.join(PoiRevision_.categoryMapping);
        // BROKEN here as we cannot use nested path for joins
        Join<PoiRevisionCategory, Category> categories = mapping.join("pk.category"); 
        conditions.add(categories.get("sections").in(sections));

        // ...

        return cb.and(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
    }
};
```

But we cannot use nested path for such joins as JPA provider (Hibernate, in my case) looks only for direct properties of `PoiRevisionCategory` class. And we cannot "join" embedded Id to our result set because it's not a manageable entity.

I'm really stuck with this issue which seems to be far from complicated when translated into SQL yet it has some complexity on the ORM-side.

Any idea is much appreciated.

Comment: In [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8657852/1267257) @gustavo mentions some `persistence.xml` setting to enable `@Embedded` entities management by hibernate. Sounds like this may help but probably can have some downsides as well. But I cannot find this parameter yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After switching completely to metamodel API it became clearer and I was actually able to join embedded entity just like I tried and failed with string api.

So the correct way is just to join like one would normally do

```
Join<PoiRevisionCategory, PoiRevisionCategoryId> pk = mapping.join(PoiRevisionCategory_.pk);
Join<PoiRevisionCategoryId, Category> cats = pk.join(PoiRevisionCategoryId_.category);
CollectionJoin<Category, Section> sec = cats.join(Category_.sections);
conditions.add(sec.get(Section_.id).in(sections));
```

And it does the thing just fine!

What a relief.

Comment: How did you make it generate a metamodel for your embeddedID? No metamodel exists for mine...

Comment: @Amalgovinus, Hi, it's been a while since I've written this and I no longer have access to the code itself, but I do not remember any issues with metamodel generation.

Comment: I wound up just doing away with the embeddedID and adding a surrogate key, it's too much of a pain to manage a natural key with the criteria API

Comment: Cannot blame you for that :) It's often much easier to go with surrogate keys when dealing with ORMs. I was just obsessed with a database-purist point of view back in the day.

Comment: @Amalgovinus Metamodel generation can be done using hibernate-jpamodelgen; which then needs to be configured/added to your maven pom, so it e.g. runs during maven 'generate sources' phase.  Please consult [JPA-metamodels with maven](https://jinahya.wordpress.com/2014/03/29/jpa-metamodels-with-maven/) for some guidelines.