# How to create a Hibernate criteria over multiple entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to implement a Hibernate criteria query that returns an entity based on parameters that refer to multiple
other tables that are not directly related to my entity and I don't know how to accomplish this task. The following are
my entities:

```
@Entity
class User {

    @Id
    private long id;

}

@Entity
class Device {

    @Id
    private long id;

}

@Entity
class Configuration {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    private Device device;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id.configuration")
    private Set<ConfigurationOverride> configurationOverrides;

}

@Entity
class Part {

    @Id
    private long id;

}

@Entity
class ConfigurationOverride {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Id id;

    private String property;

    @Embeddable
    class Id {

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Configuration configuration;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Part part;

    }

}
```

Now I want to find a `ConfigurationOverride` where `id.configuration.user.id = ...`,
`id.configuration.device.id is null` and `id.part.id = ...`. Basically something like the following SQL:

```
SELECT co.property
FROM configuration_override co
INNER JOIN configuration c
ON co.configuration_id = c.id
INNER JOIN User u
ON c.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN part p
ON co.part_id = p.id
WHERE u.id = 12345
AND c.device_id IS NULL
```

I tried to create the following criteria but it doesn't work:

```
session.createCriteria(ConfigurationOverride.class)
       .createAlias("id.configuration.user", "user")
       .createAlias("id.configuration.device", "device")
       .createAlias("id.part", "part")
       .add(Restrictions.eq("part.id", partId))
       .add(Restrictions.eq("user.id", userId))
       .add(Restrictions.eqOrIsNull("device.id", deviceId))
       .uniqueResult();
```

This leads to the following exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "user1_"
  Position: 209
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:106)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
        ... 130 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2116)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1899)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1875)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2611)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2594)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2423)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2418)
        at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1705)
        at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
        at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:385)
        ...
```

I use Hibernate version 5.0.1.Final.

Can anybody tell me how to do it correctly?

Comment: what is the exception you are getting here? maybe this might help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657895/jpa-criteria-api-join-through-embedded-id

Comment: @GIIRRII Sorry, I completely forgot about that. I have added the stacktrace.

Comment: @stevecross What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: It is 5.0.1.Final